# Single term for restating a question as its answer without specifying the content of the question again

Tags: single-word-requests

Take for example

> Why is this the **best**?
>   Because it is the **best**.

There is no further justification given for this to be the answer to the question.

Apparently the term for this is something along the lines of *meta, reflexive* from what I have searched.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need a single term for this circumstance](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/477289/need-a-single-term-for-this-circumstance)

Comment: @JasonBassford how is that a duplicate? It is entirely a different question, but just similar content :\

Comment: I think I've made the question better. Stella, it would be improved more if you could [edit it](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/477348/edit) to add in the actual research you did — what you looked for, what you found and where you found it.

Comment: I'm not clear that I understand you. The purported "answer" doesn't answer the question.

Comment: There may be a better term, but it's certainly circular reasoning.

Comment: Can you explain any difference between "Because it is…" with and without "the best"?

When the term for that is along the lines of meta or reflexive, can you not take the trouble to Post what you've searched?

Answer (score 1):

The example appears to a very basic form of [circular reasoning](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning) where the only support for the proposition’s being true is the ‘fact’ that it is true, with no external reasoning being brought to bear.

This is a type of [logical fallacy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies):

> reasoning that is evaluated as logically incorrect and that undermines
>   the logical validity of the argument and permits its recognition as
>   unsound.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an example of ["Begging the question"?](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question) Which "is a logical fallacy that occurs when an argument's premises assume the truth of the conclusion, instead of supporting it. It is a type of circular reasoning and an informal fallacy: an argument that requires that the desired conclusion be true. This often occurs in an indirect way such that the fallacy's presence is hidden, or at least not easily apparent."

or

[Perhaps I'm dodging the question.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evasion_(ethics)#Question_dodging)  **Because that is the best.**
The aim of dodging a question is to make it seem as though the question was answered.

Answer (score -1):

This can be called a **tautology**, although tautology also includes more nuanced forms beyond the basic "best is best" form.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tautology

Comment: Remember to include suggestions for improvement or explanations with your downvotes, esp. on seemingly correct answers. +1 for community.